# Como detectar sistema operativo con preprocesador de C

Tags: c

Quisiera hacer un programa pero hay un código que funciona solo sobre Windows y otro sobre GNU/Linux, me gustaría saber de que manera puedo utilizar las macros del preprocesador para poder hacer esto, leí algo algo al respecto, que proponía este ejemplo:

```
int main()
{

    #ifdef WINDOWS
       //Codigo de Windows
    #endif

    #ifdef LINUX
       //Codigo de Linux
    #endif

}
```

¿Cuales son las directivas de Windows?

Es decir, al hacer `#ifdef WINDOWS` esta verificando si la macro `WINDOWS` esta definida, y como debería ser esa definición arriba de la funcion `main()`?

Extra:
Codigo de ejemplo usando ifdef

```
#define PI 3,14

int main()
{
    #ifdef PI

     puts("Casa");
      #enifdef
}
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa tus preguntas antiguas y marca aquellas respuestas que te hayan solucionado el problema. Por otro lado te agradeceríamos que no andases editando la pregunta para añadir nuevas preguntas a posteriori porque entonces es complicado dar una respuesta satisfactoria... en esos casos es mejor crear preguntas nuevas

Answer (score 4):

**Existen ciertos macros, predefinidos los cuales se pueden usar para el problema que tienes:**

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    // Aca incluyes tu codigo para GNU/Linux
#elif _WIN32
    // Aca incluyes tu codigo para MS/Windows
#else

#endif
```

### Actualizacion

**Codigo Ejemplo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __linux__
#define SO "Linux"
#elif _WIN32
#define SO "Windows"
#endif

int main(void){

    printf("I <3 %s\n", SO);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> **Resultado:**
>
> I <3 Linux

**PD:** Uso Ubuntu

Comment: añadí un pedaso de codigo al final de mi pregunta, ya que tengo ua duda con ese codigo qu me comentaste tu,, cuando uno usa el ifdef le pongo un nombre al lado, como pi en mi ejemplo, entonces el preprocesador va  abuscar si antes hay algun #define PI, y si esta definido imprimira la palabra casa, pero en tu caso hay un ifdef __linux__, entonces el preprocesador va a buscar si hay algun #define __linux__ con un valor siguiendo la logica de mi pedaso de codigo añadido , me entiendes ? y en tu codigo no hay ningun define__linux__, ojala me haya explicado saludos!

Comment: @EmiliOrtega Esas directivas `__linux__` vienen definidas en el preprocesador, el compilador las interpreta porque estas ya han sido definidas antes del proceso de compilacion

Comment: @EmiliOrtega Es decir, contrario a tu constante **PI**, que tu la has definido, estas directivas estan definidas por estándares del proceso de compilacion, para permitir la compilación cruzada y la compatibilidad, espero me hayas entendido